# Ask: Replace multiple new line into single new line or br

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have problem with replace character.

If I have one textbox, and I write into textbox with many new line.

and the results I wanted a lot of new lines replaced with one or two new lines such as comments in the facebook.

I'l try this code :

```
litText.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Text1.Text, "[\\r\\n]+", "<br /><br />", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

this works if I press a lot of button enter,but this isn't works if I press button enter once then displays new line twice. I want if I press once or two button enter, fixed display once or two new line. except three times or more than two.

please your assistance and your opinions.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You want to duplicate the entire `\r\n` multiple times, as opposed to just duplicating one of them like in your example. Also you should use `@"..."` for this.

```
litText.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
    Text1.Text, @"(\r\n|\r|\n)+", "<br>", 
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: yes,  but Can i limit "\r\n", if i press button enter three times then display only two new line? such a create post wall on facebook?

Comment: You could do it with 2 replace calls. First, instead of the "+" quantifier you could use "{2,}" to match the at-least-2-times occurrences and replace with 2 <br>s. Then you have only the single occurrences left. Those you can replace without quantifier, and you have to replace them with a single <br>.